# Dynamic theme CSS editing for designer?

Tags: 7, theming

I am working on a theme with a designer.

A Drupal theme typically stores a style.css on file system which can be access via SFTP, which may not be an easy interface for a designer.

Is it possible to provide a editable theme CSS for designer (something like editing style.css in Wordpress)?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://drupal.org/project/live_css ?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. [AdaptiveTheme](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) is doing this, for example. But solutions like sftpFS or git-based, key-authenticated uploads can be more stable and will allow to keep the same workflow even after site goes public.

Comment: @PontusNilsson could you please put the comment in an answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CSS Injector](https://drupal.org/project/css_injector).

Project page says:

> Allows administrators to inject CSS into the page output based on
>   configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple CSS tweaks without
>   modifying a site's official theme -- for example, a 'nighttime' color
>   scheme could be added during certain hours. The CSS is added using
>   Drupal's standard drupal_add_css() function and respects page caching,
>   etc.